# Reading PostgreSQL data with z- values in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, z-value

I can read the tables with MapInfo from postgreSQL database but not the objects in the map. Data is with z values.

Comment: I can set the spatial type to 21.2 in the mapinfo.mapinfo map directory for the SQL server. But for the postgreSQL server, I could not find anything to handle z-values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a Map Catalog in the database.

Have a look in the [MapInfo Pro Documention](http://reference1.mapinfo.com/software/mapinfo_pro/english/17.0/MapInfoProUserGuide.pdf) on page 479: Creating a Map Catalog in the DBMS